# How to use MutableList to remove with kotlin call java?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a MutableList with generic with Int, like MutableList.
I wonder how to use kotlin call java method remove(int position) and remove(Integer object) correctly?

```
public void remove(int position) {
    if (this.list != null && this.list.size() > position) {
        this.list.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void remove(T t) {
    if (t != null && this.list != null && !this.list.isEmpty()) {
        boolean removed = false;
        try {
            removed = this.list.remove(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (removed) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's extremely clear that these operations are included in the doc

Comment: Sorry for that question is not clear! I mean call java list method remove, which has the same name.

Answer (score 3):

There are overall 4 methods for removing items in [`kotlin.collections.MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) as of Kotlin 1.2.30:

- `remove` - used to remove element once. Calls to this method are compiled to calls to the Java method `List.remove(Object o)`.
- `removeAt` - used to remove at a certain position. Calls to this method are compiled to calls to the Java method `List.remove(int index)`.
- `removeAll` - used to remove a collection, each element multiple times
- `removeIf` - remove using a predicate, each element multiple times

Below is an example of how you can use each method. In the comments you can find what each method would print to the console and a brief explanation of what it does:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val l: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1)
    println(l.remove(1))               // true
    println(l)                         // [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1] - removes first element and stops
    println(l.removeAt(0))             // 2 - removes exactly on a specific position
    println(l)                         // [3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1]
    try {
        println(l.removeAt(10000))
    } catch(e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        println(e)                            // java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10000, Size: 9
    }
    println(l.removeAll(listOf(3, 4, 5)))     // true
    println(l)                                // [6, 7, 1, 1, 1] - removes elements in list multiple times, 3 removed multiple times
    println(l.removeIf { it == 1 })           // true
    println(l)                                // [6, 7] - all ones removed
}
```

...

```
true
[2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1]
2
[3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10000, Size: 9
true
[6, 7, 1, 1, 1]
true
[6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. How about kotlin call java method? In java there is only the same method named remove() , and the meaning is not clear. Not like kotlin has method removeAt to remove the element in position, or method remove to an object.
In java without kotlin , we can use Int and Integer to distinguish the meaning of the same name method.

Comment: Kotlin renames the `remove(int)` method to `removeAt` to avoid confusion. A call to `removeAt` in Kotlin code gets compiled to a call of `remove(int)` method.

Comment: @yole Thank you for clarifying this. I was also not aware that `removeAt` would get compiled to  `remove(int)`. Also many thanks for editing and clarifying this in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i find the answer in [Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html) by myself. Kotlin will box generics 
 int to Integer if you declare the variable as Int?, because only an Object can be null.You can use the tool in android studio which can show the kotlin bytecode to find out that.

If we call java method like the question image:

```
val a:Int = 0
remove(a) // will call java method remove(int position)

val a:Int? = 0
remove(a) // will call java method remove(T t) to remove object
```

the result is different! If have better choice, we should avoid use like that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that other answers just give alternatives of `remove(int position)` but they didn't answer the question directly (according to the edit).

So you can use this code:

```
val list = mutableListOf("ah!", "I", "died!")
(list as java.util.List<String>).remove(1)
println(list)
```

Result:

```
[ah!, died!]
```

That's it! You've successfully invoked `remove(int position)` from Java.
This will raise some warnings, just ignore them.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETv/YptTglIwLsKHgXBg1@w0lRXN6mkm4CI3x7TiHMYmGHePCZhCqWMKcA@RnxtzhIpXHfWIwVt4N1BVUYGpllgCz4JXtgdazqNWuGtVytQh8UGckOvTCN0m@MMd8xokxDbBfnfGxudn7LT69/8WVvh0CjTfUr5Ag)

Comment: How about the list item's type is Int , and the mutableList is defined in java ? like new ArrayList<Integer>()

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @gekson with ArrayList there wouldn't be a conflict. `list.remove(3)` would call `remove(int index)` while `list.remove(new Integer(3))` would call `remove(Object element)`.

Comment: Yes, and we can use `list.remove(3 as Int?)` to box this integer.